# How to enforce interdependence among properties in Typescript

Tags: typescript, mapped-types, conditional-types

I am trying to enforce interdependence among properties in a general TypeScript type. The context is a reusable React component that receives props. If the component receives a text for a button, for example, then it must also receive a handler for the button; but if the component doesn't receive the text, then the handler prop should also be undefined.

This is my attempt:

```
type InterConnectedProps<
  T extends string | undefined,
  PropertyName extends string | undefined,
> = T extends string
  ? ({
      [K in T]: string;
    } & { [K in PropertyName]: () => void })
  : {
      T?: undefined;
      PropertyName?: undefined;
    };

    //Alternatively:
    
    type InterConnectedProps2<
  T extends string | undefined,
  PropertyName extends string | undefined,
> = T extends string
  ? ({
      [K in T]: string;
      //The differnce lies here: "as string"
    } & { [K in PropertyName as string]: () => void })
  : {
      T?: undefined;
      PropertyName?: undefined;
    };



type Props = {
  title: string;
  subtitle?: string;
}& InterConnectedProps2<'button1', 'handlerBtn1'> & InterConnectedProps2<'button2', 'handlerBtn2'>;

// Props should be either:
//  {title: string; subtitle?:string; button1: string; handlerBtn1 : () => void}
// or {title: string; subtitle?:string; button1: undefined; handlerBtn1 : undefined}
//Anyway, there should be no handlerBtn1 if there is no button1
```

But this doesn't work, not only because I am not verifying that PropertyName is a string (how do I introduce multiple conditions?). Even if write { [K in PropertyName as string]: () => void }, the resulting type seem not to include the second parameter (PropertyName):

type Button = InterConnectedProps<'button1', 'btn1Handler'> is just {button1: string}.

Where am I going wrong, or is there another alternative?

Thanks!

Comment: I tried and failed: [ts playground](https://shorturl.at/wyV37)

Comment: This works but it involves nesting separate types in the props: [ts playground](https://shorturl.at/mptS9)

Comment: Thanks @RobertRendell, so I guess the problem is in the type Props = {...} & InterConnectedProps<'button1', 'handlerBtn1'> 'handlerBtn2'> syntax. And following your example, probably the simplest way to enforce this interdependence is to use object for text and handler of each button etc., and avoid this InterConnectedProps type altogether.

Comment: Assuming React isn't necessary for the question (else it should probably be tagged as such), could you [edit] to provide a [mre] that shows some intended input/outputs of `InterConnectedProps<T>` (e.g., `InterConnectedProps<ABC>` should be `XYZ``) or, if you don't know that, what values should be accepted/rejected for a given `T` (e.g., `InterConnectedProps<ABC>` should allow `val1` and `val2` and reject `val3` and `val4`).

Comment: @jcalz , is this helpful? https://tsplay.dev/mp0Abm

Comment: Yes, although you should [edit] to put that description in plaintext in your question (and maybe fix the formatting while you're there?)  Anyway does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/mL8XKm) meet your needs? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz , Many thanks and sorry for my slow reply. Yes, it seems to be it. I would appreciate it if you could clarify the { [P in keyof T]?: never } part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you want to define a utility type `AllOrNone<T>` where `T` is an object type with all required properties, whose resulting type will accept either an object of type `T`, or an object with *none* of the properties from `T`.

Here's one possible way to define it:

```
type AllOrNone<T extends object> =
  T | { [P in keyof T]?: never }
```

This is a [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) type to capture the "either-or" part.  One union member is `T`, and the other is `{ [P in keyof T]?: never }`, which is as close as we can get to "an object with none of the properties of `T`" in TypeScript.

Let's examine `{ [P in keyof T]?: never }` more.  It's a [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) where each property key from `T` is made [optional](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html#mapping-modifiers) and the value type is [the impossible `never` type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#the-never-type).  So if `T` is `{a: 0, b: 1, c: 2}`, then `{[P in keyof T]?: never}` is `{a?: never, b?: never, c?: never}`.  TypeScript doesn't really have a way to *prohibit* a property.  But an optional property of type `never` is close: you can't supply a value of type `never`, so then the only "option" you have is to leave the property out entirely (or to set it to [`undefined`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#null-and-undefined) depending on your compiler settings).

---

Let's test it out:

```
type Z = AllOrNone<{ a: 0, b: 1, c: 2 }>;
/* type Z = { a: 0, b: 1, c: 2 } | 
     { a?: never, b?: never, c?: never } */

let z: Z;
z = {a: 0, b: 1, c: 2}; // okay
z = {a: 0, b: 1}; // error!
z = {a: 0}; // error!
z = {}; // okay
```

This makes sense; `Z` is either `{a: 0, b: 1, c: 2}`, or it's an object without any of those properties.

---

Now we can define `Props` by using `AllOrNone` twice:

```
type Props = { title: string; subtitle?: string; } &
  AllOrNone<{ button1: string, handlerBtn1(): void }> &
  AllOrNone<{ button2: string, handlerBtn2(): void }>;

let p: Props;
p = { title: "" };
p = { title: "", button1: "", handlerBtn1() { } };
p = { title: "", button2: "", handlerBtn2() { } };
p = { title: "", button1: "", handlerBtn2() { } }; // error
```

Looks good!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAggNnA8gJwHIHsB2EA8AVKCAD2AkwBMBnKdAIwCsIBjYAPigF4BYAKCigIAfKAG8oAbQAKUAJaYoAawgh0AMwEBdAPwAuKNgBuEZFAC+vXqEhQAWp1gIUGbDjEBDPQAYANFFp6ARl8mPQAmM1YAbl4AegAqKCtoOw5RXn5+DyhPaL4M-ygA3IyoEKhQ3NMoYRF0jLddKABXCghVOQhyYvzGlvI2jq66-iZe1vbsIZ4quJjeOAhgKAAvPRtc5fsRLJ8-QOCw00ioGJiaBTcQXk3U7a9fAoCjk7PjZHRkAEJrrZ3n08IyHeXx+t3+Z3QFyuPEs4GgkneYGot0SMmACz0lGAyDkAHNjpQmrRgGiFo0sTjMPizFAAGR1eBINBYXBiWhNYDALABTHYvG+AAWbgoC2QACFgJgAgAKACUegM6Bk5AidIZjmZLjZHK5mFCvMpuMFwvIoolerlCqVKtMUQsPAWSzAegR6CRuTAW1R6IgegARH6zB6vSSff6-Q8ddzw8aRcZzTLZaIaUdeJ6UaGMVAA5HOVh9dmI1AhXHxZLQnLk1VUzx08nM77C7ndTym8WTWby5WxNXjgC3h9eEA)