# In Typescript, how to check that if a key is present in an object, so should another one

Tags: typescript, union, intersect

This seems really silly and basic but for some reason I can't get it to work.

I want a type for a function argument to be an object that always has a key a of type string. This object can also have a key b of type string, but if it has this key, it must also have key c of type string.

Essentially, the function should have one argument of type

`{ a: string }` or `{ a: string, b: string, c: string }`.

I therefore want this to show an error if the object I pass the function is { a: 'abc', b: 'abc' } because it is missing c.

My initial thought was something like this:

```
{ a: string } | { a: string, b: string, c: string }
```

But this doesn't give me the error I am looking for. I've done some research online, but to no avail. Any ideas?

Also chatgpt was not helpful...

Comment: Are you looking for `{ a: string, b?: never, c?: never } | { a: string, b: string, c: string }`?  If that meets your needs I could write up an answer (or find an appropriate dupe target).  If not, what am I missing?

Comment: Works if you disallow the other properties specifically on the first one: https://tsplay.dev/w1L1KW I'm pretty sure this is a dupe tho...

Comment: Yeah, like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75976329/how-to-enforce-interdependence-among-properties-in-typescript for example.  Just waiting to make sure the OP is actually asking for this

Comment: That's exactly it, thank you! Sorry for the duplicate question, was hard to find the right way to phrase my question

Comment: Duplicate questions are just fine, no need to apologize (they serve as signposts that lead future users to the answer they want).